# Are there IDs that can be used to access entries on Bloomberg's Private Company Search?

Tags: finance

[Bloomberg's Private Company Search](http://www.bloomberg.com/Research/common/symbollookup/symbollookup.asp?lookuptype=private&region=all) provides access to a lot of companies. I'm currently not sure whether there's a way to access the results of this list with FIGI numbers. If so, are their special FIGI numbers that are about the company directly and not about it's shares?
Otherwise is there some other ID for companies?